# How to make spritespin auto resize fit to window?

Tags: html

I have a problem using spritespin. The canvas can not resize fit to window, I have tried CSS same which work for image to fit to window, but it didn't work. This is the example for basic usage of spritespin. [this is the example of spritespin basic usage](http://spritespin.ginie.eu/examples.html#basic-usage.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.spritespin').spritespin({
  // generate an array of image urls.
  // this is a helper function that takes a {frame} placeholder
  source: SpriteSpin.sourceArray('/images/rad_zoom_{frame}.jpg', {
    // this ramge of numbers is interpolated into the {frame} placeholder
    frame: [1,34],
    // the frame placeholder will be padded with leading '0' up to the number of 'digits'
    digits: 3
  }),
  // Specify the display width and height of the frame.
  // Optionally the size of the container can be defined with CSS.
  width: 480,
  height: 327,
  // Sense controls the direction and speed of the animation for mouse/touch interactions.
  // Here a negative value is chosen to invert the rotation, so the animation 'follows' the drag direction.
  // Values towards 0 will slow the animation down.
  sense: -1
});
});
</script>
```

How to make spritespin auto resize fit to window?

```
<div class="spritespin spritespin-instance with-canvas" unselectable="on" ><div class="spritespin-stage" ></div><canvas class="spritespin-canvas"></canvas></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the spritespin function call set "responsive : true".